# Custom numbering of tables, equations and figures

Tags: floats, numbering

I am writing a chapter for a book. The chapter number is `5.4`. The chapter has multiple sections. I would like all the figures, tables and equations in my chapter to be labelled as `5.4.X`. For example, the first equation should be labelled as `5.4.1`, the first table should be labelled as Table `5.4.1`, the first figure should be labelled as Figure `5.4.1`, and so on. How should I do this? I am writing this chapter independently and I do not have access to any files, etc. that will be used for the final typesetting. I am using documentclass `article` for writing the chapter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the following instructions to the document's preamble:

```
\newcommand{\chprefix}{5.4}
\renewcommand\theequation{\chprefix.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\chprefix.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\chprefix.\arabic{table}}
```

That way, if the publisher decides to change the chapter number from `5.4` to, say, `6.7`, only the `\chprefix` macro needs to be adjusted.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\chprefix}{5.4}
\renewcommand\theequation{\chprefix.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\chprefix.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\chprefix.\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:first} a^2+b^2=c^2 \end{equation}

\setcounter{figure}{5}
\begin{figure}[h] \caption{A figure} \label{fig:middle} \end{figure}

\setcounter{table}{19}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{A table} \label{tab:last} \end{table}

Cross-references to equation (\ref{eq:first}), figure \ref{fig:middle}, and table \ref{tab:last}.

\end{document}
```